# Scheduling starting a service before another service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, services, scheduled-tasks, windows-services

I have a service that needs to be started only **BEFORE** another *3rd party service* who's Startup Type is Automatic.

How is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dependency to your 3rd party service.

Check this related question on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed